# Test scenario of Database components

Tags: regression-testing, database, test-data, non-functional

For one new project we have a requirement to add multiple "Database Collation" support to the system, means the system will create DB on any specified DB Collations for Unicode, ANSI supported languages. This will not create the problem for new DB creation because in DB create script we can specify collation.
As per DBA, we can achieve this by changing DB level collation and all Temp table creation query for existing DBs. Here my concern is, from a testing perspective, what sort of changes we need to test\verify like:

1. What kind of test scenario we need to cover for this.
2. What are the effects on the existing data stored in Table after these changes?
3. How we can verify this data in testing?
4. Any specific data set we require to create for this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are testing the requirement "the DB must support multiple collations".

In that case, my test strategy would involve creating and editing the collation in the tables, and checking that the data does not change, or changes as specified in your requirement - I am assuming your requirement says something like "*all accents will be removed when converting from collation A (which supports accents) to collation B (which doesn't support accents)*". If this is not clear in the requirements, you need to go back to your developer or RA (requirements analyst) and ask them.

The test data would have specific strings (or other types) that break when collation is changed (for example, try adding characters not supported by the collation). You will have to research each collation to find out what are the best candidates.